# Interpreting a Parametric Graph

Tags: parametric-functions

I have graphed the parametric equation and located when the slope is equal to zero. Now I want to take this value and turn it into the max, value or y value. How can I do this? 
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
d = Pi/4;
v0 = 400;
g = 9.8;

x[t_] := t v0 Cos[d]
y[t_] := t v0 Sin[d] - 1/2 g t^2

max = Maximize[y[t], t]
```

[image]

```
ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 70},
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[{x[t] /. max[[2]], max[[1]]}]}]
```

[image]

Or

```
sol = First @ Solve[D[y[t], t] == 0, t]
```

[image]

```
{x[t], y[t]} /. sol
```

[image]